# raspbian - sudo apt-get update not working

Tags: raspbian, apt

I have problems when trying to update the apt repositories.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg                      

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you connected to a network?

Comment: try `ping www.google.com` to see if you are connected to the network or not.

Comment: am sure that am connected to the network  ,i got ths :   """64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=43 ttl=49 time=100 ms
64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=44 ttl=49 time=99.8 ms
64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=45 ttl=49 time=98.5 ms
64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=46 ttl=49 time=96.5 ms
64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=47 ttl=49 time=95.7 ms
64 bytes from par03s14-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.78): icmp_seq=48 ttl=49 time=97.0 ms

Comment: Try a different mirror. Your network may be blocking your current one.

Answer (score 6):

There is DNS related issues with mirorrdirector. See answer here : [cannot connect to mirrordirector.raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27479/cannot-connect-to-mirrordirector-raspbian)

You can remove

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main firmware
```

from `/etc/apt/sources.list` then add another mirror found [here](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors) to this file.

Or, you can change `/etc/resolv.conf` to something like :

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: I got ths error after changing /etc/apt/sources.list   : W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Can't mmap an empty file
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine just if you edit "sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf" and have manually IP Static Config Settings the line for "static domain_name_servers=192.168.x.x 8.8.8.8" for example.  Save and reboot.  Remember 192.168.x.x is Your Local Router/Gateway IP Address. This works for me!

Comment: It's fine that setting a static IP helped in your case, but do you have any indication that the OP has the same problem?