# Unable to install from apt-get

Tags: apt, samba

I have searched for a solution and before I explain the issue, I have run `apt-get update` but I still get the problem. `sudo apt-get upgrade` is also experiencing the same problem.

I am assuming `mirror.umd.edu (129.2.73.2)` is currently unavailable but I am not entirely sure.

---

I am trying to install Samba:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```

However after a couple of minutes of waiting on this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  attr libaio1 libasn1-8-heimdal libfile-copy-recursive-perl libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldb1 libntdb1 libroken18-heimdal libtdb1
  libtevent0 libwind0-heimdal python-crypto python-dnspython python-ldb python-ntdb python-samba
  python-talloc python-tdb samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools update-inetd
Suggested packages:
  python-crypto-dbg python-crypto-doc bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools smbldap-tools winbind
  heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr libaio1 libasn1-8-heimdal libfile-copy-recursive-perl libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldb1 libntdb1 libroken18-heimdal libtdb1
  libtevent0 libwind0-heimdal python-crypto python-dnspython python-ldb python-ntdb python-samba
  python-talloc python-tdb samba samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
  tdb-tools update-inetd
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,735 kB/8,696 kB of archives.
After this operation, 44.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main python-tdb armhf 1.3.6-0+deb8u1 [14.0 kB]
0% [Connecting to mirror.umd.edu (129.2.73.2)]
```

I get this:

```
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libexpat1-dev armhf 2.1.0-6+deb8u3
  Could not connect to mirror.umd.edu:80 (129.2.73.2), connection timed out
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libpython2.7-dev armhf 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Unable to connect to mirror.umd.edu:http:
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main python2.7-dev armhf 2.7.9-2+deb8u1
  Unable to connect to mirror.umd.edu:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-6+deb8u3_armhf.deb  Could not connect to mirror.umd.edu:80 (129.2.73.2), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.9-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.umd.edu:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.9-2+deb8u1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirror.umd.edu:http:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried the suggestion and ran with `--fix-missing` but no luck.

It is happening on two different pi units. Is there an alternative way to install everything I need? I tried searching for an alternate mirror but wasn't having much luck. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same issue. Looks like UMD is having trouble right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround to continue installing the package. I followed the [accepted answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27479/cannot-connect-to-mirrordirector-raspbian).

I changed my apt-get source in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to this:

```
deb http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

[(Mirror list here)](http://here) then did `sudo apt-get update` and tried to install again. It worked that time.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues, but the website seems to be working now.

http://mirror.umd.edu/