# Cannot fetch from mirror nus.edu.sg

Tags: raspbian, boot, noobs, apt, update

I just start using rpi and quite a newbie

i run

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

The update thing is successful, however , i cannot do the upgrade part,
there are some package they fail to fetch
It's said `Failed to fetch http://mirror.nus.edu.sg` with `hash sum mismatch`

I did some searching and found out that this mirror only limited in NUS campus. But how to change to other mirror, as i go to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The url there is `archive.raspbian.org` which is nothing related to the NUS thing but my pi keep fetching from NUS mirror.

Please help

Comment: Change the mirror like described here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27479/cannot-connect-to-mirrordirector-raspbian

Comment: i cannot edit the sources.list file. its say cant open file to write. do you know why