# How do I add a new source to /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Doing `$ sudo apt-get update`  gives `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`. After doing some digging i found this [Cannot connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27479/cannot-connect-to-mirrordirector-raspbian-org) which explains that there is a DNS issue with mirrordirector, and to change the source in /etc/apt/sources.list.

I did so and my /etc/apt/sources.list went from looking like this

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

to looking like this

```
#deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian/
```

but this gave the error

```
E: Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried fixing it by adding `wheezy main contrib non-free rpi` after the new source, but that just gave `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

I did also try uncommenting `deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi` but that just gave the same error again

I also did `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` and that gave

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=36.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.601/36.601/36.601/0.000 ms
```

Comment: It's not clear here whether DNS is working generally or not; the fact that the error is different implies it is, but to test that you need to `ping google.com`, a hostname, not an IP address.

Comment: ```pig google.com``` gives ```PING google.com (216.58.211.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr48s13-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.211.174): icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=16.3 ms```. I can access the internet through my raspberry pi, but sometimes when trying to open a link I get ```SSH handshake failed```

Comment: Don't bother! Wheezy is obsolete. There will NEVER be any updates.

Answer (score 3):

Raspbian **Wheezy** is deprecated and not supported since years. Its repository is archived and you cannot use it anymore. It's not a DNS issue, it's simply not available. Try to address the archived repository with this entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```